# Google Location KML shows weird latitudes

Tags: location, kml, google-visualization

I have exported my complete google location history as KML in order to geotag photos, that I have taken in Japan and New Zealand. Whilst the locations for Japan are very accurate, every entry for New Zealand is wrong. The latitude is always way over 300. Per definition it can't be outside a range of between -90 and +90. In the location history map everything is fine. Do I have to recalculate the latitude?

```
<gx:coord>176.2470279 391.3479882 293</gx:coord>
```

This is an example for a location in Rotorua, New Zealand.

The coordinates I get: 176.2470279, 391.3479882
It should be more like this: 176.2470279, -38.141135

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Google Location.

Comment: Seems like you should post this as an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem. At least in my case I found a solution:

1. Export one single day as KML directly in the timeline (correct
   coordinates).
2. Export the whole timeline file through Takeout (wrong coordinates).
3. Calculate the difference between the right and wrong numbers. In my
   case the latitude was off by exactly 429,4967296 each time.
4. Use Excel or a script to subtract the difference from the wrong
   coordinates.